# Would we expect the space between different Oort clouds to be empty?

Tags: astronomy

If we consider a few solar systems to be like to image below (yes, I know it's overly simplistic), and each solar system has a cloud similar to the Oort cloud (the yellow globes), would the space between them be mostly empty? You can see a bit of the space not covered by the clouds as the small pink area to the left of centre and the dark purple area to the right of centre.

This is my thinking: Even at that distance, small bodies would be travelling fairly fast. If one gets knocked out of its cloud into the space between clouds it would quickly (in galactic terms) cross into anther solar system, most likely on a highly elliptical orbit (orbit is perhaps not the right word as there's a good chance it would be ejected from the next solar system after passing close to its star). Any bodies moving slowly in that area (not obviously from another cloud) would be slowly attracted to one of the stars, so it seems unlikely on very long time-scales to expect much to be there. Is my thinking correct?

[image]

Comment: It's all full with "stuff", if you are looking for a mental model of what's really far out there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_comet. One wouldn't expect anything else, the capture velocity at the edge of the Oort cloud is on the order of 1m/s!